# Capturing the hot keys from a thread using c#;

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to capture the ctrl + alt + Q hot keys, which works perfectly.
But, i want to use this in a background application. Since my application does not have any forms, i want to use the same code inside a class file.

i am confuse, because i cannot write a event handler [keypressed] in class file.
Instead i want to use the keypress in thread.

Please help.

```
 public DialogResult Result; 
    KeyboardHook hook = new KeyboardHook();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // register the event that is fired after the key press.
        hook.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs>(hook_KeyPressed);
        // register the control + alt + F12 combination as hot key.
        hook.RegisterHotKey((ModifierKeys)2 | (ModifierKeys)1, Keys.Q);
    }

    void hook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    { 

        Result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, you want to log off?","Log off"
                ,MessageBoxButtons.YesNo
                ,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        if (Result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture a global hotkey without a form, I'm afraid you cannot.

The reason is that global hotkeys are sent to a window handle (and processed in wndProc, aka. the message pump)

So basically the way Windows works, you cannot use global hotkeys without a form to received them.

I'm not entirely certain this is what you want to do however. But on the other there won't be any local hotkeys without a form either, so I cannot see what else it might be.

You may want to further clarify your question a bit (no offense)

Comment: Okay then, i will do that using a form. But is there any way to make the form invisible, it shud not even be in the taskbar.

Possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, possible. I capture the hotkey while my app is invisible and bring it to the front.

Comment: I am using the following, but still i am getting the form.

private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
         }

Comment: A form cannot startup being invisible unfortunately.
You can "fake" it by hiding it in its OnActivate event, however it'll show up briefly as it starts up.

Alternatively you have to create your own ApplicationContext and run this in void main (Application.Run(yourContext)) - this is however not as simple as it may sound :-(